# jmeter Ant build error. TestPlan class not found

Tags: performance, testing, ant, jmeter

I am trying to create a jmeter test and run it with Ant following this tutorial: http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php

I think i have done everything correct but when i run Ant i get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Trendkiller>ant
Buildfile: C:\Users\Trendkiller\build.xml
   [jmeter] Executing test plan: C:\Users\Trendkiller\EuscreenWebTest.jmx ==> C:
\Users\Trendkiller\JMeterResults.jtl
   [jmeter] Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\Trendkiller\EuscreenWeb
Test.jmx
   [jmeter] Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find the
 TestPlan class!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

my build.xml is:

```
<project name="EuscreenWebTest">
<taskdef
name="jmeter"
classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"/>
<jmeter
jmeterhome="apache-jmeter-2.6"
testplan="C:\Users\Trendkiller\EuscreenWebTest.jmx"
resultlog="C:\Users\Trendkiller\JMeterResults.jtl"/>
</project>
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?
Sorry if I am doing something profoundly wrong, I am kinda new to Ant and jmeter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `jmeterhome="apache-jmeter-2.6"` in your case relative path to Jmeter home dir?

It should be set either as absolute path e.g.:

```
jmeter.home=c:\jakarta-jmeter-2.6
```

or relative - relative to build.xml:

```
jmeter.home=../jakarta-jmeter-2.6
```

Check this.

Comment: yes, it was in the home directory so this wasn't the problem. 
I restarted the process from scratch and now it works.. I have no idea what the problem was.. I followed the exact same steps.. anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: It is not jmeter.home. It should be jmeterhome

Answer (score 1):

One of JMeter's oddities is that Ctrl+S will **just** save what is currently selected in your Test Plan. This means that you can save over a large chunk of your test plan with just 1 sampler. It's possible that this happened: you'll still see a jmx with the correct name, but its contents are much smaller, and not at all what you want.

Using Ctrl+Shift+S will save your entire test plan with a 'Save As.' I recommend using this shortcut exclusively- it will ask you if you're sure you want to save over your last save each time you do it, but it's well worth not losing hours of scripting.